Boy avoids shower and survives Holocaust
I am looking for a ~2000's drama movie which shows, during the Holocaust, a mother and her son forced by authorities to take a train to a concentration camp.
Once there, there is a scene where children were asked by Nazi agents to have their shower. His whole life, the boy never liked to shower. And this, in my memory, is what makes all the movie's beauty; because even in the concentration camp he did everything not to have a shower. He preferred to hide in the dormitory. In fact, he just avoided death because he then saw that all the other children did not come back.
When the Nazi reign comes to an end, the camp is rescued. Both mother and son are still alive and find each other before going back home by train.

This sounds a lot like "La vita è bella/Life is Beautiful" (1997).
A Jewish family is taken to the concentration camp, with father and son separated form the mother. The boy survives the shower, I think by hiding away from it (it was a while since I've watched it, so I'm not sure).
During their long stay in the camp, the father convinces his son that the whole camp is the game of hiding from the guards, and thus gets him through the experience both alive and emotionally unscratched. The father dies in the end (I think protecting his son), but the son doesn't witness that and, among other survivors, finds his mother, so they end up reunited.

Nice try! But I'm not looking for this one. The one I saw had darker images and the whole movie looked more recent. Thank you anyway!

How about A boy in striped pyjamas 
Sounds similar but not the same like you said
i should have commented this but since i don't have enough reputation i couldn't do it.

Thanks for the idea! But I already checked this one and it isn't the one I am looking for.
